# DNA results of Amarna dead?

Tags: ancient-egypt, archaeology

In the Egyptian city of Amarna, [archaeological expeditions](https://www.google.com/amp/relay.nationalgeographic.com/proxy/distribution/public/amp/news/2013/03/130313-ancient-egypt-akhenaten-amarna-cemetery-archaeology-science-world#ampshare=http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2013/03/130313-ancient-egypt-akhenaten-amarna-cemetery-archaeology-science-world/) have revealed numerous graves of people who appear to have worked very hard while being malnourished. One [recent article](http://www.charismanews.com/world/65504-newly-discovered-slave-graveyard-dates-to-biblical-era) on the subject says that Mary Shepperson said, "We hope that future DNA analysis of the bones might clarify the geographical origins of the North Tombs Cemetery skeletons." Have the DNA analysis results been published? If so, what are the findings?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That article seems to be about the [North Tombs](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2017/jun/06/did-children-build-the-ancient-egyptian-city-of-armana-) cemetery, which was excavated as part of the [Amarna Project](http://www.amarnaproject.com/) in 2015. Like you, I'm really looking forward to the publication of the DNA data.

However, it's still a bit early to expect publication of all the details from the 2015 excavations. When they are available we should be able to read copies on the Amarna Project site, either on the [publications page](http://www.amarnaproject.com/pages/publications/dying_at_amarna.shtml) or the [Northern Cemeteries page](http://www.amarnaproject.com/pages/recent_projects/excavation/northern_cemeteries/).

Just for information, annual reports from the South Cemetery excavations (including reports on the human bioarchaeology) are available for the years 2005-2013 on the [South Tombs Cemetery](http://www.amarnaproject.com/pages/recent_projects/excavation/south_tombs_cemetery/) page of the Amarna Project website. I don't remember seeing any DNA analysis from that site though.